# PigLatin translate

Tags: c#, foreach

I will create a program that translates English words into Pig Latin ... My problem with the code found below, is that the only word in the last index of the array as reported in the results? Does anyone see the error?

Thanks in advance

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnTrans_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {

        string engWordText = engWord.Text.ToString();
        string let1;
        string restLet;
        int position;
        string pigLatin = "";
        string vokal = "AEIOUaeiou";



         // split the sentence into individual words
         //string[] words = engWordText.Split(' ');
         string[] transWord = engWordText.Split(' ');

         // translate each word into pig latin
         foreach (string word in transWord)
         {
                 // check for empty TextBox
                 try
                 {
                     let1 = word.Substring(0, 1);
                     restLet = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
                     position = vokal.IndexOf(let1);

                     if (position == -1)
                     {
                         pigLatin = restLet + let1 + "ay";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         pigLatin = word + "way";
                     }

                     // display the translation
                     latinInput.Text = pigLatin.ToString();
                     engWord.Clear();

                 }
                 catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show("Du måste skriva in ett engelskt ord", "PigLatin",
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                 }

         }


         } // end method translateButton_Click

         // pressing enter is the same as clicking the Translate Button
         private void engWordText_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
         {
         // allow user to press enter in TextBox
         if ( e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter )
         btnTrans_Click( sender, e );
         } // end method inputTextBox_KeyDown


         } // end class PigLatinForm
```

Comment: You want `pigLatin +=` instead of `pigLatin =`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the value of `pigLatin` to the text box's Text property at the end of each loop, which means it will only have the last value that was assigned to it. Try this:

```
 List<string> plWords = new List<string>();         
 // translate each word into pig latin
 foreach (string word in transWord)
 {
         // check for empty TextBox
         try
         {
             let1 = word[0];
             restLet = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);

             if (!vokal.Contains(let1))
             {
                 pigLatin = restLet + let1 + "ay";
             }
             else
             {
                 pigLatin = word + "way";
             }

             plWords.Add(pigLatin);
         }
         catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Du måste skriva in ett engelskt ord", "PigLatin",
             MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         }
 }

 engWord.Clear();    
 latinInput.Text = string.Join(" ", plWords.ToArray());
```

As a bit of a bonus, here's how you can make this operation quite a bit cleaner using Linq:

```
private static string MakePigLatin(string word)
{
    const string vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";

    char let1 = word[0];
    string restLet = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);

    return vowels.Contains(let1) ? word + "way" : restLet + let1 + "ay";
}

private void btnTrans_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
     var plWords = engWord.Text
                          .Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                          .Select(MakePigLatin);

     latinInput.Text = string.Join(" ", plWords);
     engWord.Clear();    
}
```

Comment: Thank You =) But now i get "Error 1 No overload for method 'Join' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: Please try my updated last line: `latinInput.Text = plWords.ToArray().Join(" ");`

Comment: Sorry. Third time's a charm. :) If you're using .NET 4.0 or above, you can leave out the `.ToArray()` part.

Comment: A list is a bit of overkill, you can simply fix this by changing `pigLatin =` to `pigLatin +=` and moving `latinInput.Text = pigLatin` outside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, of course you can make the program work just by changing the `=` to `+=`, but then you're left with a ~20 line `foreach` loop whose sole function is to populate one particular textbox with pig latin. Separating it into two steps: (a) [convert a list of English words to pig latin], (b) [populate the textbox with the list of words] results in more modular and reusable code.  And yes, you could move the `latinInput.Text = pigLatin` outside of the loop, but I still think it's a better practice to produce a list of words rather than just a single string.

Comment: No, it's a `foreach` loop that fills a `string` variable with some text, as opposed to a `List<string>`, and _after_ the loop the string gets assigned to the textbox. There's really no difference between my suggestion and your code, only the latter adds `list.Add()` and `String.Join()` calls.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry, I was responding to your comment as it was before you edited it. The difference is that a `foreach` that builds a list of words can be factored out and used elsewhere, where having a list of individual words could be useful (for instance, to populate a dropdown or listbox). Having a string as the result the operation leaves you with fewer possibilities.

Comment: You Ain't Gonna Need It... But if you put it that way, have an upvote.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you. :) I see your point about the YAGNI, but as a general guideline, I think it's more useful to treat collections of items as collections of items and not wedge string concatenation into the midst of it. That allows formulating concise solutions like the Linq example I've just added.